# Zebra Browser Print, labels did not print in numbered order

Tags: zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl

We have numbered labels that we want to print with Browser print, we send each label like this:

```
^XA^FO100,100^A0N,50,50^FD Label: 1^FS^XZ
^XA^FO100,100^A0N,50,50^FD Label: 2^FS^XZ
^XA^FO100,100^A0N,50,50^FD Label: 3^FS^XZ
```

But the printed labels are never in order and it's random, for example 3,1,2.

Does anyone know a ZPL command to set the numbering of each label for the printer to print them in the order defines 1,2,3, ...etc. or any other solution? I thought about the possibility to send a delay for each label, but I think that would be my last resource, anyway, I'm not sure how to establish delays.

After reading the documentation, the most similar topic talks about the sync/async:

> Queued Communication JavaScript is asynchronous, but the printer is
> not. Sending multiple query commands to the printer in succession will
> most likely result in all of the responses being concatenated together
> into the response of the first read attempted
>
> The Zebra.Printer object will manage sending the query commands,
> reading and parsing the responses, and calling the proper callback
> methods so that requests are handled one at a time.
>
> For example, if the following code is run:
>
> ```
> zebraPrinter.getStatus(function(status){}, function(error){});
> zebraPrinter.getConfiguration(function(response){}, function(error){});
> zebraPrinter.getSGD("device.friendly_name", function(value){}, function(error){});
> ```
>
> Each request command will be sent to the printer, and the response to
> that command will be read and parsed before the next request is sent.
> Each request's callback function will only receive the device response
> for that request.

Comment: The printer always prints in the order received. If that is not you are observing, it's not the printer's fault. How are you sending the labels?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I send them in order. I think browser printer might have a bug changing the order doing some async print. Even if I send the labels in order, I think bowser print handles them at the same time giving random positions to each label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up merging the ZPL in one big file with all the labels.